# How ansible copy file from remote windows to remote linux without local copy and ssh install in windows

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, file-transfer

OS: Wk16 vs Debian 10.4
Ansible: 2.9

Hi all

I need to send a file from remote Windows to remote linux without to copy in local without to install ssh package in Windows server.

```
A Win_server <-- Ansible role executor -- B Ansible_host         C linux_host
|
|                                                                   ^
|___SENDING FILE_______________________________________TO___________|
```

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I putted the SSH in Windows how @guistela sayed.

I Installed "Posh-SSH" on Windows host with ansible:

1. Manual Download from:
   https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH.
2. Send file to Windows host contains files to send.
3. Install with microsoft steps: [Installing PowerShell modules from a
   NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7.1#installing-powershell-modules-from-a-nuget-package).
4. Possh-SSH use commands, more info here:
   [powershell-scp-to-transfer-files-between-windows-linux](https://thedarksource.com/powershell-scp-to-transfer-files-between-windows-linux/):

- Open ports
- Send file
- Close ports

This 4 general steps permits send files from windows to linux hosts.

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

Checkout syncronize module at Ansible Documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html

Also, be aware to stablish direct ssh connection between targets.

Hint: It's possible to activate ssh on windows and stablish connection to the linux machine. Take care of the risks!

Other way is to use fetch and copy to do the triangle copy using Ansible server as elbow.

Comment: Hi! But I need without ssh. I update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way for your case... Use ansible localhost as elbow and let it go!

Comment: Yes I can but I need without this solution. I search how put the file content to var and after write a file with the content of var.